# How to delete setup audit trail

Tags: setup-audit-log

I can query the SetupAuditTrail records but failed to delete some of them. Neither Apex nor the developer console can help me out. Anyone has the gadget to fulfill this mission？ Thanks.

```
List<SetupAuditTrail> s = new List<sObject>();
s.addAll( [ SELECT Id FROM SetupAuditTrail WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY ] );
Database.delete(s);
```

Comment: According to the documentation here -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_setupaudittrail.htm, it is not possible to update and/or delete such entries (and that is logical)

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, part of the local team is trying to earn much more permissions from global team... long story

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't delete the setup audit trail because it supports only two calls query(), retrieve().

Please see [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupaudittrail.htm) to learn more

When you attempt to delete, you will run into the following error

[image]

```
    List<SetupAuditTrail> deleteAuditTrailList = 
    [SELECT Id,
        Action,
        CreatedBy.Name,
        CreatedDate,
        Display,
        Section 
     FROM SetupAuditTrail 
     LIMIT 5];
System.debug('results are' + deleteAuditTrailList);

Delete deleteAuditTrailList;
```